# Magento 2.2 Authorize Net Payment Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, authorize.net

Working on **authorize.net** sandbox integration in Magento 2.2. I have followed instructions in setting up authorize net credentials. But when i try to place an order i receive an error as below

```
"An error occured on the server. Please try to place the order again"
```

But when i check the **authorize.net** sandbox account panel, there is an successful payment transaction. Also when checking in **Sales->Orders** there is a new order with no payment received.

Also using [this link](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000570793-Error-placing-order-with-Authorize-net-Sandbox-account-An-error-occurred-on-the-server-) i tested the response of transaction.dll it says failed to load response.

My assumption is payment is authorized but it seems no response is received from authorize net.

Any assistance would be really appreciated .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess that it happen bcoz of another module. Suggesting to you enable the error  log  and check the exception and system .log at vart folder